# Trouble finding a particular polynomial.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

How would you find a polynomial which has positive derivative when $1<x<2$, and negative derivative when $x\lt1$ or $x\gt2$.

Answer (score 0):

Find $\int -a(x-1)(x-2)\, dx$ with $a>0$.

$$-a\int \left(x^2-3x+2\right)\, dx=-a\left(\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{3x^2}{2}+2x\right)+C$$

Any polynomial of this form fits the condition.